# How do I display and edit other posts within the 'Edit Post' area of Wp-Admin Dashboard

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, dashboard, wp-editor

I'm wondering how to edit the 'New Post/Edit Post' area of Wordpress.

I want to create a new 'Screen Element' like the plugins do.

I want this area to display all posts with a corresponding taxonomy tag to the post being edited.

I know how to write the code to make this work on the frontend. I just don't know how to apply this area to the backend.

How do I create new areas in the backend? Plugins like Yoast SEO and Toolset create a new box there.

Do I need to create a plugin to do so, or can I write a function for the functions.php?

Thanks!

Comment: Found what I'm looking for. [add_meta_box()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) allows you to create what are called 'meta boxes' in the WP-admin area. This is very cool. I found a great article with a little tutorial as well. Hope this helps the others!
[Here's the Article WIth A tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-meta-boxes-to-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code and explanation from [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-meta-boxes-to-wordpress/) about adding a custom meta box to the WordPress dashboard new post area.

```
function custom_meta_box_markup()
{
    
}

function add_custom_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Custom Meta Box", "custom_meta_box_markup", "post", "side", "high", null);
}

add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");
```

`add_meta_box` should be called inside `add_meta_boxes` hook.

`add_meta_box` takes 7 arguments. Here are the list of arguments:

- `$id`: Every meta box is identified by WordPress uniquely using its id. Provide an id and remember to prefix it to prevent overriding.
- `$title`: Title of the meta box on the admin interface.
- `$callback`: `add_meta_box` calls the callback to display the contents of the custom meta box.
- `$screen`: It's used to instruct WordPress in which screen to display the meta box. Possible values are "post", "page", "dashboard", "link", "attachment" or "custom_post_type" id. In the above example we are adding the custom meta box to WordPress posts screen.
- `$context`: It's used to provide the position of the custom meta on the display screen. Possible values are "normal", "advanced" and "side". In the above example we positioned the meta box on side.
- `$priority`: It's used to provide the position of the box in the provided context. Possible values are "high", "core", "default", and "low". In the above example we positioned the meta box
- `$callback_args`: Its used to provide arguments to the callback function.